# Use a result twice in a pipeline

Tags: pipe, paste

I have two programs progA and progB

./progA outputs a list like this :

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
```

and ./progB take the result of progA as an argument and also outputs a list :

```
b1
b2
b3
b4
```

I can pipe them like this :

```
./progA | ./progB
```

Now I want to paste the two lists, something like this :

```
a1  b1
a2  b2
a3  b3
a4  b4
```

With a temporary file I can do

```
./progA > tmpA
./progB tmpA | paste tmpA /dev/stdin
```

but I don't want to write in a file or call progA twice.

How can i do this ?